# Parsing section of the file with specific heading using awk , sed , grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file that i s broken down to bunch of different headings. I need to grep out certain fields under particular heading. For example I want to print names under PRIORITY USERS heading. I can grep for this segment using grep and print the names ( Like grep -A 10 "PRIORITY USERS "| grep name: ) but I need to limit my output only to names under PRIORITY USERS heading.  The problem is that the number of entries under each heading varies , so  I cannot use a fixed number with grep -A option

Can you assist please?

Input file

```
USERS:

           name: 286
           fields1
           fields 3 

           name: 123
           fieldx: test


PRIORITY USERS:

           name: jack
           field1:  8
           name: Joe


           name: bob
           field1: xyz

           name: tempo
           kind: Text


 SEGMENT3 

           name: ginger
           name: max

 Non-USERS

           Name: JOJO
```

Output  should be :

```
PRIORITY USERS:  

    name: jack 
    name: bob
    name: tempo
```

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: Do you REALLY have some header lines that start at the beginning of the line and are suffixed with `:` (e.g. "PRIORITY USERS:") while others can have spaces before/after them and no `:` after them (e.g. (" SEGMENT3 ")? If so, how can we tell a heading from any other line in the file? If not - edit your question to make your sample input accurate so we can try to help you fix your real problem and not some problem you don't actually have. Also why is `name: joe` not in your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '/SEGMENT/{a=0}a{$0=$1}/PRIORITY/{a=1}a' file
PRIORITY USERS:
           name: jack
           name: bob
           name: tempo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:space:]]?[^[:space:]]/ { inSect = ($0 ~ ("^[[:space:]]?" sect "[[:space:]:]*$") ? 1 : 0) }
inSect && ($0 ~ "^[[:space:]]+" field ":")

$ awk -v sect='PRIORITY USERS' -v field='name' -f tst.awk file
           name: jack
           name: Joe
           name: bob
           name: tempo
```

The above is complicated due to your input format being so wildly variant  with some header lines starting with space, others no, some having immediate trailing semi-colons which others have spaces instead, etc. and it assumes you just missed `name: joe` from your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

cat sample.csv

```
USERS:

           name: 286
           fields1
           fields 3

           name: 286
           fields 4

PRIORITY USERS:

           name: Jack
           field1:  8
           name: Joe

 SEGMENT3

           name: ginger
           name: max

 Non-USERS

           Name: JOJO
```

sed -n '/PRIORITY USERS/,/SEGMENT3/p' sample.csv | grep name

```
   name: Jack
   name: Joe
```

'/PRIORITY USERS/,/SEGMENT3/' PRIORITY USERS are the start pattern and SEGMENT3 is the end pattern, we only print out the lines between those 2 patterns and then get the `name`

Comment: Hi - Thx for the feed back .. It worked for one segment of the file , but when I  tried  another it listed name under additional segments .. not sure why it work for one segment and not anotehr

Comment: try removing 3 from end pattern "SEGMENT3"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the top-level headings can be characterized as occurring on lines that start with at most one blank.  If that's the case, then the following has the advantage of not requiring knowledge of the top-level heading after the target heading:

```
sed -r -n '/^ ?PRIORITY USERS/,/^ ?[^ ]/ {/name:/p ; }'
```

(Some versions of sed require -E instead of -r for extended regex support.)

In any case, there is no need to invoke both `sed` and `grep`.

One advantage of using 'awk' here is that you can use the "?" in the regular expressions without having to set a flag:

```
awk '/^ ?PRIORITY USERS/ {s++; next}
     s==1 {if (/^ ?[^ ]/) {s++} else if (/name:/) {print}}'
```

Comment: Hi thx - there is no blank line above each segment - sometimes there is sometimes there is not ,, I am not sure if the sed command will run properly .. the awk command I can not get to work at all

Comment: @theuniverseisflat - You misunderstood.  In your example, the headings occur on lines in which there is either no space in column 1, or exactly one space in column 1.  I've tested the awk program using three different `awk`s (Mac OS awk  20070501, gawk and mawk).

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= 'f{print;exit} /PRIORITY USERS:/{f=1}' file

           name: ack
           field1:  8
           name: Joe
```

I guess, also there is an unwritten requirement to filter out lines non-names.  For that, slightly change the script

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= 'f{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/name:/) print $i;exit}
     /PRIORITY USERS:/{f=1}' file

           name: ack
           name: Joe
```

UPDATE: based on the updated input file, this will produce the names list

```
$ awk '/SEGMENT3/{f=0} f&&/name:/; /PRIORITY USERS:/{f=1}' file

           name: jack
           name: Joe
           name: bob
           name: tempo
```

Note: Your output sample is missing "Joe".  If instead you missed "bob", there was a nice joke!

Comment: Hi thx again for ur help .. I amended the input file. Ur solution only print the first set of data under PRIORITY USERS ( sorry I failed to include that there are additional data under each segment " Please see modified input text above

Comment: What indicates the end of block?  SEGMENT3 tag?

Comment: Hi sorry for delayed response .. each section is clearly identified by name . there are at least 10 section and the appear in order PROCESS: USERS: MOUNTS SERVICES etc ETC.. Thx again for helping